# Minimum IAM policy required to run Boto functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-iam

I'm trying to run some boto functions in a python script. I need to create an IAM policy with the minimum required permissions to execute those boto functions. Is there a good way I can relate those boto functions to the AWS IAM permissions that I'd need to execute them.

For example, here are the boto modules (python) I have. What IAM permissions would a user need to run them? Is there a good way to find this?

```
boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region
boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region
boto.ec2.connect_to_region
boto.ec2.instance.Instance
boto.ec2.elb.loadbalancer.LoadBalancer
boto.ec2.autoscale.group.AutoScalingGroup
```

Comment: here you go --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/OperationList-query.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing it, how can I use that to tell me what permission I need to run `boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region` would need?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/control-access-using-iam.html the docs have everything you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 1:1 correlation between the functions you listed and an API call to AWS.

If you use a `client` function, then you need the specific permission for that function, such as:

```
response = ec2_client.describe_instances()
```

This command would require `ec2:DescribeInstances` permission.

boto3 also provides `resource` functions that provide a more object-like experience, such as:

```
instance = ec2_resource.Instance('id')
```

Such functions could call any number of underlying API calls, so it is not easy to determine the permissions required for such calls.

You can use **AWS CloudTrail** to view the underlying API calls that were made, so that permissions can be determined.

Comment: AWS CloudTrail lists some of the API calls but not all (for example S3)